# Tag review: [tag:application-message]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[application-message](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-message) seems to address only `mqtt`-related questions - per its tag wiki and the [two questions](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-message) that use it so far.

So while "application message" is certainly a term used with `mqtt` it could be used outside it as well. I suggest to either rename it to include `mqtt` (something like [mqtt-application-message](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt-application-message)) or get rid of it at all if it does add enough value.

What do you think?

Comment: Get rid of it. MQTT is enough. It's a *messaging protocol*, no need to have a specific tag for the message in my opinion.

Comment: Well, @Helmar, you know, you have the powers, you need to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, get rid of it. It's a generic term and can be used outside of MQTT. Also I think [application-message](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-message) itself doesn't add much value.